# GC Operation on unregistered thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gdb, malloc

I am getting the following error on OS X Lion 10.7 in my application. I have pinpointed what is causing the error, but want to find out if this is a bug in 10.7 or if something has changed that I am missing.

```
malloc: *** auto malloc[3677]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug.
```

The stack trace from GDB when running `bt` on the breakpoint:

```
#0  0x00007fff90742b44 in auto_zone_thread_registration_error ()
#1  0x00007fff9073a9a4 in auto_zone_allocate_object ()
#2  0x00007fff8f36335e in _Block_copy_internal ()
#3  0x00007fff8a9d7e9d in HALC_ProxyIOContext::StopIOProc ()
#4  0x00007fff8a9d7dc6 in __HAL_HardwarePlugIn_DeviceStop_block_invoke_30 ()
#5  0x00007fff8a9b8521 in HALB_Executor::DoIt ()
#6  0x00007fff8a9b84ce in HALB_Executor::Run ()
#7  0x00007fff8a9d7ce9 in HAL_HardwarePlugIn_DeviceStop ()
#8  0x00007fff8a9d7c6d in HALPlugIn::DeviceStopIOProc ()
#9  0x00007fff8a9d7bb1 in AudioDeviceStop ()
#10 0x00000001044b381c in AUHAL::StopHardware ()
#11 0x00000001044b397e in AUHAL::AUIOProc ()
#12 0x00007fff8a9d5362 in HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop ()
#13 0x00007fff8a9d4ac9 in HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOThreadEntry ()
#14 0x00007fff8a9d4984 in HALB_IOThread::Entry ()
#15 0x00007fff8fb2f8bf in _pthread_start ()
#16 0x00007fff8fb32b75 in thread_start ()`
```

The code that is causing this Garbage Collection thread error is:

```
NSSound *completedSound = [NSSound soundNamed:@"Glass"];
[completedSound play] //this line is causing the error;
```

All that line does is play one of the system sounds that are registered on the system as selected by the user. To me it seems like a bug, and I have filed a bug report just in case.

Anybody else experienced this?

Comment: I'm experiencing it as well. Not sure if it's serious. I tried forcing the sound playback onto the main thread, no luck.

Comment: It is a bug in Lion that has been reported and is being worked on. AFAIK there currently is no workaround.

Comment: I filed it, too, a while back and later it was marked as "duplicate of 9341336"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed I have. The stack trace seems pretty similar as well. It seems to happen when a sound file stops playing, and I am pretty sure that it wasn't happening under 10.6. It doesn't seem to affect the actual running of my app, though.

There are also other cases of this error (with WebKit, mostly) that showed up on google while I was looking for the cause, and they all suggested that it wasn't really any sort of problem.

What was the bug report number?

Comment: Yeah, the trace shows AudioDeviceStop () so figured it was the end of the playing that causes it, as the sound does play. I have put a wrapper around the call to make sure it only works with SL and lower, until I can figure something out.

It definitely never happened on 10.6 as the code I have worked perfectly for the app.

The bug ID is: 9928419

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any third-party audio plugins installed, and remove them one by one. The crash report will show all loaded bundles.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same message with the speech synthesizer stopping.