# Play NSSound two times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to play a NSSound two times except its shorter than 10sec then i want to wait until the 10sec are done and then start the second one.

But I already have a problem playing the same NSSound twice.

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MessageArrived" ofType:@"wav"];
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath byReference:YES];
[sound play] //It plays the fist time
[sound play] //I get the following Error and it doesn't play a secont time
/*malloc: *** auto malloc[498]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug.*/
```

Can someone tell me whats the reason for this error?
How can I handle this?

Is there another way i have to do this?

Comment: Seems like you're using Garbage Collection. If possible you should move your code to ARC instead, a lot of the frameworks are a bit fragile when GC is enabled.

Comment: What do I have to do to get ARC working and disable GC?
I started this project befor ARC was available...

Comment: The new Xcode 4.3.1 has automatic conversion of projects from GC to ARC, under the **Edit > Refactor** menu.

Comment: OK, thanks... Doing this had fixed the message from GC but not the sound playing problem.
But... I found what was causing the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a loot of searching and trying to fix it I got the solution for my problem...

```
NSSound *sound = [NSSound soundNamed:@"MessageArrived"];
BOOL res = [sound play];
NSLog(@"%d", res);
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(playSecondSound:) toTarget:self withObject:sound];

-(void)playSecondSound:(NSSound*)sound
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10-[sound duration]];
    [sound stop];
    BOOL res = [sound play];
    NSLog(@"%d", res);
}
```

I found out that even when the sound has finished I have to call [sound stop] before starting the second.

Answer (score 0):

The sound is already playing when you call the second play method, obviously a bug in garbage collection as the second play should be ignored, but it will not be an issue with what you want to achieve.

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MessageArrived" ofType:@"wav"];
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath byReference:YES];
[sound play];

//Will play the second time after 10.0 seconds have passed.
NSInteger wait = ([sound duration] < 10.0) ? 10.0 - [sound duration] : 0.0; 
[sound performSelector:@selector(play) withObject:nil afterDelay:wait];
```

Comment: Might work but i still get the "malloc: *** auto malloc[589]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug." message when the second one should be played... So the secont one there is no sound...

Comment: The error message is just a warning about garbage collection that got added in 10.6 and should not be an issue. It's a bug that [Apple must resolve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010233/gc-operation-on-unregistered-thread) that you have no control over. There are several of these all over the framework, especially in 32-bit code over the 64-bit version of the framework.

Comment: But the second Sound doesn't get played... I can listen to the first one but the second one is missing...

Comment: Running the code works like a charm on my system. Could it be that your sound is longer than 10 seconds? Add "NSLog(@"Duration: %f", [sound duration]);" to find out how long your sound is. If that can be the case you want to add a minimum to the amount of wait, I edited the code to add the wait. Otherwise, it's a bug with init as I am using the "[NSSound soundNamed:@"Morse"]" for testing the above code.

Comment: The Sound is about 6.04 seconds long...
I just tried soundNamed:@"MessageArrived" too, again its working for the first play but not for the second... whats going on with this thing...

Comment: Try flipping it to [NSSound soundNamed:@"Morse"] find out if the issue is with your specific sound or something else. A blank project with the above code in applicationDidFinishLaunching works on 10.7.3/11D50b.