# How to play a wav file placed in Documents directory in OSX using objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio, audio-player

I have been trying to play an audio file but unable to succeed.

**SoundFilePath**:
/Users/admin/Library/Containers/com.abc.myApp/Data/Documents/MyAudioSample1.wav

**NSSound:**

```
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath byReference:YES];
sound.volume = 1;
sound.delegate = self;
[sound play];
```

Only once out of 5 times my audio is played.

**AVFoundation:**

```
 NSURL* file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];        
 AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
 [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: have you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716198/play-nssound-two-times

Comment: Yes, logic is same, except it adds sleep to play 2 sounds. and wav file is picked from the bundle. In my case, only one file in documents directory needs to be played but the code is not working.

Comment: code works only once after 5 times...cant understand y is this

Answer (score 0):

Add `[audioPlayer play];`

You are preparing to play but not playing it. After adding above line your code will be:

`NSURL* file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath]; 
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayeralloc]initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];`

Hope it helps